# Google Charts Legend Position Top Not Working

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

> You can use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7o0pjgg/2632/) for testing

Full Code:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['bar']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');
    data.addRows([
        ['2001', 500, 1200, 816, 200],
        ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
        ['2003', 125, 819, 200, 578],
        ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 500]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        legend: {
            position: "top",
            alignment: "",
            textStyle: {
                    color: "#999"
                }
            },
        chart: {
            title: 'Year-by-year coffee consumption',
            subtitle: 'This data is not real'
        },

        series: {
            2: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            },
            3: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1
            }
        }
    };

};
```

**Question** :

I want to display legend above of the chart. I have used legend position : top. But it is not working. I can move legend either left side or right side without a problem changing legend position value.

But I can't move legend top or bottom. Why is that? What was the my mistake?

Comment: you're using a _Material_ chart vs. _Classic_ -- there are many options that are not supported by _Material_, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: @WhiteHat What can I do to convert this chart to classic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to use the correct library, as `jsapi` is out of date and should no longer be used,
according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes).

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

This will only change the `load` statement:

**old** load statement...

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

**new** load statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

---

Next, as seen above, for *classic* charts, use --> `packages: ['corechart']`
instead of `'bar'`

Google has provided a chart option, to style *classic* charts **similar** to *material*:

```
theme: 'material'
```

When creating a *classic* chart, use the following namespace:

```
google.visualization.ColumnChart
```

vs. *material*

```
google.charts.Bar
```

---

See the following working snippet:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');
  data.addRows([
    ['2001', 500, 1200, 816, 200],
    ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
    ['2003', 125, 819, 200, 578],
    ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 500]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 64,
      left: 64,
      right: 32,
      bottom: 32
    },
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    isStacked: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      textStyle: {
        color: '#999'
      }
    },
    title: 'Year-by-year coffee consumption'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  drawChart();
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="chart_div"></div>
```

Note: the only advantage to *material* is having multiple stacks,
in *classic*, you cannot group multiple stacks.

---

**UPDATE**

There are no options you can change to position the legend to top or bottom, it is simply not supported.

The only solution would be to manually build a custom legend; 
following is an *example* of how this could be done:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');
  data.addRows([
    ['2001', 500, 1200, 816, 200],
    ['2002', 163, 231, 539, 594],
    ['2003', 125, 819, 200, 578],
    ['2004', 197, 536, 613, 500]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'coffee consumption',
      subtitle: 'This data is not real'
    },
    height: '100%',
    isStacked: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    series: {
      2: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      3: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      }
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(container);

  drawChart();
  window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
  function drawChart() {
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }

  // add legend marker
  function addLegendMarker(markerProps) {
    var legendMarker = document.getElementById('template-legend-marker').innerHTML;
    for (var handle in markerProps) {
      if (markerProps.hasOwnProperty(handle)) {
        legendMarker = legendMarker.replace('{{' + handle + '}}', markerProps[handle]);
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('legend_div').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', legendMarker);
  }

  // chart ready event
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var legend = document.getElementById('legend_div');

    // get colors from chart
    var colorPallette = [];
    var colorsBottom = [];
    var colorsTop = [];
    var stacks = container.getElementsByTagName('*');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(stacks, function(stack) {
      switch (stack.tagName) {
        case 'path':
          if ((stack.getAttribute('fill') !== null) && (stack.getAttribute('fill') !== '#ffffff')) {
            if (colorsTop.indexOf(stack.getAttribute('fill')) === -1) {
              colorsTop.push(stack.getAttribute('fill'));
            }
          }
          break;

        case 'rect':
          if ((stack.getAttribute('fill') !== null) && (stack.getAttribute('fill') !== '#ffffff')) {
            if (colorsBottom.indexOf(stack.getAttribute('fill')) === -1) {
              colorsBottom.push(stack.getAttribute('fill'));
            }
          }
          break;
      }
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < colorsBottom.length; i++) {
      colorPallette.push(colorsBottom[i]);
      colorPallette.push(colorsTop[i]);
    }

    // clear previous legend
    legend.innerHTML = '';

    // add legend marker for each Y axis column - skip X axis --> i = 1
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      var markerProps = {};
      markerProps.index = i;
      markerProps.color = colorPallette[i - 1];
      markerProps.label = data.getColumnLabel(i);
      addLegendMarker(markerProps);
    }

    // add "hover" event to each legend marker
    var currentSelection;
    var markers = legend.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(marker) {
      marker.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
        currentSelection = chart.getSelection();
        var marker = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (marker.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'DIV') {
          marker = marker.parentNode;
        }
        var columnIndex = parseInt(marker.getAttribute('data-columnIndex'));
        chart.setSelection([{column: columnIndex}]);
      }, false);
      marker.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
        chart.setSelection([]);
      }, false);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.chart {
  height: 100%;
}

#legend_div {
  color: #999;
  font-family: Roboto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  top: 0px;
  width: 60%;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.legend-marker {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.legend-marker-color {
  border-radius: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="legend_div"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart_div"></div>

<!-- template for building marker -->
<script id="template-legend-marker" type="text/html">
  <div class="legend-marker" data-columnIndex="{{index}}">
    <div class="legend-marker-color" style="background-color: {{color}}"></div>
    <span>{{label}}</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check your answer

Comment: _note: the only advantage to material is having multiple stacks,
in classic, you cannot group multiple stacks..._ This is the problem....